# find mongoose using model with hierarchy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for the mongodb database to find object with value lat > 0 (latitude of user). But the result is empty.
What is the correct query? In my case `{pos:{lat:{ $gte : 0 }}}` is incorrect.

the code:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String, 
    activated:{ type:Number, min:0, max:1 },
    pos:{ 
        lat:{ type:Number, min:-90. , max: 90.},
        lon:{ type:Number, min:-180., max:180.}
    }
});

User.find({pos:{lat:{ $gte : 0 }}},function(err, vals) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(vals.length);//shows zero length
});
```

But if I'm trying to find

```
User.find({ activated:1 },function(err, vals) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(vals.length);//shows correct size
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
User.find({"pos.lat":{ $gte : 0 }}, function...
```